# How can I bind `vue ui` to another IP? (vue-cli 3)

Tags: vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli in docker, and it's necessary to bind services to the LAN IP, or to `0.0.0.0` in order to access them 'locally'.

I expected `--host 0.0.0.0`, but that's not there.

`$ vue ui
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://localhost:8000`

`$ vue ui -h
  Usage: ui [options]
  start and open the vue-cli ui
  Options:
    -p, --port <port>  Port used for the UI server (by default search for awailable port)
    -D, --dev          Run in dev mode
    --quiet            Don't output starting messages
    --headless         Don't open browser on start and output port
    -h, --help         output usage information`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) inside a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) instance for development and had the same issue initially.

It looks like the -H / --host option was added in vue-cli version 3.1.0:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/2568

```
$ vue --version
3.1.3

$ vue ui -h
Usage: ui [options]

start and open the vue-cli ui

Options:
  -H, --host <host>  Host used for the UI server (default: localhost)
  -p, --port <port>  Port used for the UI server (by default search for available port)
  -D, --dev          Run in dev mode
  --quiet            Don't output starting messages
  --headless         Don't open browser on start and output port
  -h, --help         output usage information

$ vue ui -H 0.0.0.0
  Starting GUI...
  Ready on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

This solved my issue.